# csproj from VS2008 fail to compile with mono xbuild

Tags: c#, mono, csproj, xbuild

I use Mono 2.6.4 compiled from source on CentOS to compile a VS2008 project in C#.
Some csproj compile, but this one doesn't, here is the output of xbuild /t:detailed :

```
/opt/mono-2.6.4/lib/mono/2.0/Microsoft.CSharp.targets: error : Error executing task Csc: Input string was not in the correct format
                Error executing task Csc: System.FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format
  at System.Int32.Parse (System.String s) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ParseOrigin (System.String origin, System.String& filename, System.Int32& lineNumber, System.Int32& columnNumber, System.Int32& endLineNumber, System.Int32& endColumnNumber) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.LogEventsFromTextOutput (System.String singleLine, MessageImportance importance) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ProcessOutputFile (System.String filename, MessageImportance importance) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ExecuteTool (System.String pathToTool, System.String responseFileCommands, System.String commandLineCommands) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.Execute () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.BuildTask.Execute () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
        Task "Csc" execution -- FAILED
        Done building target "CoreCompile" in project "/mnt/virtualbox/Project/(API)/Base/Base.csproj".-- FAILED

OnError for target CoreBuild skipped due to false condition:  '$(RunPostBuildEvent)' == 'Always' or '$(RunPostBuildEvent)' == 'OnOutputUpdated'
        Target _GetCompileOutputsForClean:
        Done building target "_GetCompileOutputsForClean" in project "/mnt/virtualbox/Project/(API)/Base/Base.csproj".

        Target _RecordCleanFile:
        Done building target "_RecordCleanFile" in project "/mnt/virtualbox/Project/(API)/Base/Base.csproj".

Done building project "/mnt/virtualbox/Project/(API)/Base/Base.csproj".-- FAILED
```

Anyone has an idea ? Thanks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might already be fixed in svn. I changed that code to use regex some time back. Could you try this with a mono daily build [1]? Or just file a bug with the project file and i'll check it.

1. http://mono.ximian.com/daily/

Comment: This looks like the same issue: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=594541 , already fixed in svn.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bug in xbuild.  File a bug with a test case to get it fixed:

http://www.mono-project.com/Bugs